# When particle number can change in quantum physics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, special-relativity

Let me write a paragraph from D.Tong lecture notes on [QFT-chapter2](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft.html) when he is talking about non-relativistic limit of scalar quantum field theory :

> A related fact is that the conserved charge $Q=\int{d^3x : \psi^\dagger \psi:}$       is the particle number. This remains conserved even if we include interactions in the Lagrangian of the form:
>
> $L = V (\psi^\star \psi)$
>
> So in non-relativistic theories, particle number is conserved. It is only with relativity, and the appearance of anti-particles, that particle number can change.

My question is what forbids us from adding a term like $\psi^4$ or $\psi^3$ to the Lagrangian of this non-relativistic scalar field theory?   Because it seems that such term can change the particle number.

In the old version of question I had guessed that the thing that forbids us is Galilean invariance (or classical nature of theory. Is it right?

> **Update**: the question is reformulated (butchered!) completely.

Comment: [For interacting particles, states with definite particle number aren't energy eigenstates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fock_state).  This means that there exist macroscopic systems, such as the photon gas in a laser or the atoms in a Bose-Einstein condensate, where "particle number" isn't a good quantum number for the system.

Comment: So non-relativistic quantum mechanics can handle variable particle number? Seems strange. I don't think it is possible.

Comment: Second quantization in non-relativistic quantum mechanics is just a device for doing calculations in a more convenient manner as mentioned in many body texts. But the second quantization in quantum field theory is really a new physical idea.

Comment: the non relativistic harmonic oscillator was at the base of the idea of creation and annihilation operators http://www2.ph.ed.ac.uk/~ldeldebb/docs/QM/lect12.pdf

Comment: The statement can be used for Feynman diagrams too, which is the only reason that QFT has taken such roots in theoretical physics,  that it "is just a device for doing calculations in a more convenient manner" . Physics is about observations and predictions from a theoretical model, after all.

Comment: By "is just a device for doing calculations in a more convenient manner" I meant that it can't explain the situations with variable particle number and is just a tool to study systems with large number of particles (In contrast to QFT that can describe such situations).  Of course I agree with what you said anna v.

Comment: For real particles to be "born", one needs the sufficient energy and this implies a relativistic consideration. But often we deal with quasi-particles whose occupation numbers change and the total number of quasi-particles is not conserved. Phonons, for example.

Comment: Considering 1), the answer is no. This is due to the fact, that you can design completely nonrelativistic quantum theories on Fock spaces using second quantization. This is frequently done in many-body-physics, its basically going from canonical ensembles to grand canonical ensembles. I am however not sure if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Daniel, what you mentioned is true for change in the number of quasi-particles as is mentioned by Vladimir. I'm asking about real particles. Also see my comment about second quantization above,

Comment: Presently, 3 votes (including from me) are in for re-opening the question. You can yourself also vote it for re-open; just a reminder.

Comment: I can't vote my own post. Or should I do it from somewhere else? (which I'm not aware of :-) )

Comment: I think it would nicer if you tell the guy to edit the question and if he didn't after a certain time(say 24 hours) then you put the question on hold. You are doing exactly the opposite! Put the question on hold and see what happens next!. Just a suggestion :). As another option if the number of up votes for re opening was less than the number needed for put on hold action it would be more efficient. It is not fair for a question to remain on hold because someone doesn't check his profile(I guess there is no doubt that may question at present form has no ambiguity and shouldn't remain on hold)

Comment: That charge number is conserved in the non relativistic regime is an observational fact. Any lagrangian that aims to describe the data has to have this property by choice of construction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whether or not you're allowed to include non-particle-number-conserving terms in your Hamiltonian has nothing to do (at the mathematical level) with whether your system is relativistic or not - it has to do with what Hilbert space you're using.  If your Hilbert space takes the form $\mathcal{H} = \otimes_{i=1}^n \mathcal{H}_1$, where $H_1$ is a single-body Hilbert space (e.g. the space of $L^2$-norm complex functions on $\mathbb{R}^d$), then it can only describe states with exactly $n$ particles.  Therefore a term like $a^4$ isn't even a linear operator on this Hilbert space at all (because it takes you out of the Hilbert space) so it wouldn't make any sense to include it in your Hamiltonian, which must be a linear operator on the Hilbert space.

On the other hand, if your Hilbert space, say, takes the form $\mathcal{H} = \oplus_{n=0}^\infty (\otimes_{i=1}^n \mathcal{H}_1)$, then it contains different "sectors," each of which consists of a definite number of particles.  On this Hilbert space, a term like $aaaa$ makes perfect sense - it takes a state in the $n$-particle sector to the $n-4$-particle sector.  All this is equally true whether or not your system is relativistic.

That's all math, now here's the physics.  *Fundamental* particles with mass $m$ can only be created or destroyed in processes involving energies greater that $m c^2$ - scales that are common in relativistic situations.  So empirically, elementary particle number changes all the time in high-energy situations.  So a fixed-particle-number Hilbert space just isn't powerful enough to accurately describe high-energy physics.

On the other hand, if you're working with an $n$-body nonrelativistic system where $n$ is reasonably small (like, say, five), then you can describe the system using the usual many-body Hilbert space $(\mathbb{R}^{d})^n$.  Since the system is nonrelativistic, the particle number won't change, so you can get away with just using a fixed-particle-number Hilbert space.

If you want to tackle a truly many-body nonrelativistic condensed-matter system, where $n \sim 10^{23}$, then particle number will be conserved but the Hilbert space will be completely intractably gigantic.  So in practice you restrict yourself to the lowest few excited states which only have a few quasiparticles, and you work in the many-*quasiparticle* Hilbert space (where now "many" means "more than one, but not a huge number").  However, empirically, quasiparticle number can change in many condensed-matter systems (most notably superconductors), so you again need to work in the indefinite-particle-number Hilbert space.

Comment: TLDR: relativistic system = fundamental particle number not conserved; nonrelativistic system = fundamental particle number conserved, quasiparticle number not (necessarily) conserved.

Comment: It's kind of a shame that many people don't encounter indefinite-particle-number Hilbert spaces until they study relativistic QFT.  They get the impression that there's something inherently relativistic about the notion.  But in fact it's just a practical matter: you don't always *need* such fancy Hilbert spaces in nonrelativistic contexts, but there's nothing stopping you from using them.

Comment: In fact, in my experience, long after you first study QFT, you realize that a lot of the concepts are just advanced concepts from *nonrelativistic* QM, that ideally you should have mastered before you started studying QFT ... okay, sorry, now I'm just rambling.

Comment: Interesting. If nothing new shows up I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: The mass, as a central charge of the Galileu álgebra, would not prevent interactions that not conserved particles?

Comment: @Nogueira I think that's a deep enough issue that it deserves a separate SE question