# Why does non-relativistic QFT necessarily conserve particle number?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, quantum-information, quantum-electrodynamics

My QFT lecturer said:

1. Particle number is fixed in QM (I understand this.)
2. Particle number can vary in relativistic QFT, but not in non-relativistic QFT. (and he said '$E=mc^2$ is at the root of this)

Why can't particle number vary in non-relativistic QFT? Why can't you use a non-relativistic Lagrangian with coupling terms that cause particle number to not be conserved?

I got confused by this question: [When particle number can change in quantum physics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/265980/when-particle-number-can-change-in-quantum-physics).

Is the reason just that the energy scales needed to create a new particle are typically too large unless you account for $E=mc^2$ (what I think the above question suggestions), or is there a more rigerous reason, or is it not the case at all?

Obviously quasi-particle numbers can vary in non-relativistic QFT, but what about actual particles? My assumption is that the QFT framework facilitates varying particle number, regardless of the Lagrangian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually when we say that e.g. an electron is assumed non-relativistic, we mean that it has a velocity $v \ll c$.

If "non-relativistic QFT" means QFT for energies much smaller than $m c^2$, then there are no physical mechanisms allowing the creating or annihilation of physical fundamental particles.

> Why can't you use a non-relativistic Lagrangian with coupling terms that cause particle number to not be conserved?

I suppose you can, it would just not be a physical Lagrangian.

Comment: Okay so its not something intrinsic (somehow) in the framework of a non-relativistic QFT. Its just that when you use the correct (physical) Lagrangian and take the non-relativistic limit, the energies are (by definition of non-relativistic) too small to create new particles?

Comment: I would say so. As you say, you can always write up terms which are non-conserving, but they just don't describe anything physical. I might suggest asking your lecturer for clarification on what exactly they meant, if that is possible.

Comment: Yeah you're answer makes perfect sense. I think I assumed he meant that if you don't include an $mc^2$ term in the Lagrangian, somehow particle nunber must be conserved in the framework. But I think he really meant that, for physical Lagrangians, you obviously need sufficient energy to create new particles

Comment: What about the "creation" of phonons?

Comment: @Quantumwhisp Phonons are quasiparticles, not fundamental particles.

Comment: @Codename47 I misread the section on quasiparticles in the initial question. But in general for a qft, there isn't a distinction between quasiparticles and particles, no?

Comment: @Quantumwhisp I think that the OP means "*particle physics QFT*" in the title.